# Which power should a radio transmitter have to overcome attenuation of 100 km thick ice crust?

Tags: radio, radio-frequency

Imagine I put a floating probe inside the subglacial ocean of Encelado or Europa: how much power should my radio have to be able to communicate from external surface with the probe?
Or, in different words, how much attenuation do 100 km of solid ice cause to a radio signal at, say, UHF frequency?